# How run embeded scripts in templates

Tags: javascript, angular, instagram

I have controller to show the instagram embeded code

```
<div class="instagram_here" [innerHtml]="instagram_embeded_code"></div>
```

But it show just blank instagram block. 
[image]
I think the problem in script

```
<script async="" defer="" src="//www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script>
```

It does not run after code embeded and image are not loading. How make this component correct?

Comment: Maybe create the script after the div has the embed code...

Comment: @Luca I can't edit the instagram embeded code.

Answer (score 1):

Scripts are removed from the templates for security purposes.

If you want to embed a script, add it to the `index.html` file. Otherwise, use a dependency or a REST API.

Comment: Script are not removed. I was try to add it in index.html, but nothing changed. Embeded code doesn't work

Comment: Scripts are removed. If they're not, feel free to provide a [mcve], because on **[this sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mzvakk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**, the scripts are indeed removed.